# [Ruby 1.9][Windows] Sending Ctrl-C interrupt signal to a spawned subprocess

Tags: ruby, windows, process, interrupt

I have a main script in Ruby 1.9.3 running on Windows. It's will start another Ruby script that runs as a daemon, do its own stuff, then end the daemon by sending an "INT" signal. The main script and daemon don't otherwise do any data exchange.

The daemon itself can run as a standalone, and we terminate it with Ctrl-C. Here's the part that prepares it for the signal:

```
def setup_ctrl_c_to_quit
     Thread.new do
        trap("INT") do
          puts "got INT signal"
          exit
        end
        while true
          sleep 1
        end
      end
end
```

I am currently having trouble having the main script launching and terminating the daemon. Currently, I can start the daemon through spawn and detach as such:

```
def startDaemon
  @daemonPID = spawn("ruby c:/some_folder/daemon.rb", :new_pgroup=>true, :err=>:out)
  puts "DaemonPID #{@daemonPID}"
  daemonDetatch = Process.detach(@daemonPID)
  puts "Detached Daemon . Entering sleep...."
  sleep 15
  puts "Is daemon detached thread alive? => #{daemonDetatch.alive?}"
  puts "Attempt to kill daemon...."
  Process.kill( "INT", @daemonPID )
  sleep 5
  puts "Is daemon detached thread still alive? => #{daemonDetatch.alive?}"
end
```

Ideally, the last puts statement should show daemonDetatch.alive? to be false. In reality, not only does daemonDetatch.alive? still ended up being  true by the end, the daemon also can be found as still running in both the Task Manager and other 3rd party apps such as Process Explorer.

The first question I have is with the spawn(...) function. The [official documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn) said that :new_pgroup "is necessary for Process.kill(:SIGINT, pid) on the subprocess" send it determines whether the subprocess becomes a new group or not. I've toggled with this paramter, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Also, I am planning to give [this solution](http://blog.robseaman.com/2008/12/12/sending-ctrl-c-to-a-subprocess-with-ruby) a try, which involves using the win32-process gem. I am just wondering if there are other solutions out there.

[Edit]

I have validated the PID of the daemon obtained in the main script, the daemon itself (with $$), and Process Explore, and they are all the same.

I have gotten suggestion from many others to just use "taskkill /f" to terminate the daemon. That will indeed end the daemon, but the daemon cannot trap the "TERM" or "KILL" signals the same way it traps "INT", meaning it will be unable to run its clean-up/quit routine.

Comment: Did you verify, that the PID you use for killing the daemon, really matches the one you see in Process Explorer? I know, it should be the case, but spawning sub processes on Windows is tricky and often gets one into trouble (in my experience at least).

Comment: Yes, the daemon's PID is the same in the Process Explore, the main script, and the daemon's $$ variable.

Comment: And can you kill it from Process Explorer? Just yesterday I had the strange case that I wasn't able to kill a process neigher from Process Explorer nor from Task Manager.

Comment: One more idea: You could shell out and use [taskkill](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx).

Comment: @user1934428 Yup. I can kill the daemon through Process Explore, though I usually do it with Task Manager, if I ever need to end it manually.

Comment: Using taskkill will indeed terminate the daemon. As I have added, though, this method have its caveat.

Comment: Well, some signals can never be caught. This is by design - otherwise someone could write a rogue program which can never be killed! This applies in a POSIX architecture to the signals KILL and STOP. The TERM signal should be trappable, but maybe Windows doesn't adhere to the standard in this respect. The responsibility is on the sender: Don't send a non-trappable signal, unless you really have to.